# Updating a website with some Data in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a python function that crawls a website and returns a dictionary every minute. I want to show this dictionary in a table on a website and in case of any change in the crawled data to update the website and make a chrome notification. How I could I do this with Django?

Comment: I assume from the tags you want to do this with Django?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-send-notifications-to-your-web-app-using-python-ba490b893292/) and [this](https://github.com/pushpad/pushpad-python) for your push notifications, and [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-send-web-push-notifications-from-django-applications) are some django specific ones. With updating the website, you may be restricted by caching, so you'll have to use some sort of javascript AJAX request to get that data from the server avoiding cache